# Is it possible to remove namespace prefix from a managed package?

Tags: managed-package

I have installed a managed package. I need to remove my managed package. I am not able to uninstall the manage package. Is it possible to remove? Please can any one help me out what do I need to change. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error its throwing while you try to uninstall that package?

Comment: You can use the "uninstall" link to remove a managed packages, but if any local code or components have been added that depend on what is in the managed package (e.g. its objects or fields) those dependencies will have to be removed first. As susanoo asks, what problem are you seeing?

Comment: @susanoo chidodori I am not getting  any error..

Comment: Hi Keith I am not able to "uninstall" in my managed package because there is no any option..

Comment: I have some screenshot but I am not able to post. Create-->Package--> Developer Setting-->Edit-->1)Package types Allowed:Managed and Unmanaged2)Managed Package:None3)Namespace Prefix:MyForce click the Edit button--> Click the Continue--> have two option. 1)Register a namespace perix contain:- My Namespace Prefix:MyForce 2)Choose the package you want managed:I am not getting any piclist value in Package to managed option-->Click the Review My Selections again getting same problem. How can i resolve this issue..

Comment: You can create the namespace first and then add a package (created via the "new" button" on the packages page) later. (Once you have set the namespace that is then fixed for the org. So to change the namespace you would need to move your code to a new org.) Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes Keith I agree your point. I try to move my all code to another org. I think there is no way remove namespace without move the code to new org am I right?